# Mutex + RegisterWaitForSingleObject = External exception C000070A

Tags: delphi, winapi

Пытаюсь воспользоваться функционалом [RegisterWaitForSingleObject](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-registerwaitforsingleobject) для ожидания мьютекса, но при вызове получаю External exception. Не просто "отказ в регистрировании коллбака", а именно EE.

Что я делаю не так? В сети в основном идут примеры на коллбаки к хендлам процессов, но документация утверждает, что мьютексы так же могут использоваться в этом вызове.

Попытка №1, самая простая:

```pascal
const
  MutexName = 'Global\TForm20Mutex'; // префикс Local и без префикса не меняют результат.

// callback-функция
procedure WaitCallback(lpParameter: Pointer; TimerOrWaitFired: Boolean); stdcall;
begin
  Sleep(10); // сюда вызов не доходит.
end;

procedure TForm20.btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  bResult: BOOL;
begin
  FMutexHandle := CreateMutex(nil, False, MutexName);
  if FMutexHandle = 0 then
    RaiseLastOSError;

  bResult:= RegisterWaitForSingleObject(FCallbackHandle, FMutexHandle,//
      WaitCallback, nil, INFINITE, //
      WT_EXECUTEONLYONCE or WT_EXECUTELONGFUNCTION); // ExternalException здесь

  if not bResult then // сюда управление не доходит.
    RaiseLastOSError;
end;
```

Попытка №100500, динамическая загрузка (перед этим - перекрывал статическую линковку, результат тот же).

```pascal
type
  TRegisterWaitForSingleObject = function(out phNewWaitObject: THandle; hObject: THandle;
      CallBack: Pointer; Context: Pointer; dwMilliseconds: ULONG;
      dwFlags: ULONG): BOOL; stdcall;
  // вместо out param пробовал var и PHandle в качестве типа первого параметра.

var
  RegisterWaitForSingleObject: TRegisterWaitForSingleObject;

procedure TForm20.btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  hKernel: THandle;
  bResult: BOOL;
begin
  hKernel:=LoadLibrary('kernel32.dll');
  if hKernel = 0 then
    RaiseLastOSError;

  RegisterWaitForSingleObject:=GetProcAddress(hKernel, 'RegisterWaitForSingleObject');
  if @RegisterWaitForSingleObject = nil then
    RaiseLastOSError;


  FMutex := TMutex.Create(nil, False, MutexName);

  FCallbackHandle := 0;
  bResult := RegisterWaitForSingleObject(FCallbackHandle, FMutex.Handle, @WaitCallback, 
      nil, 100, WT_EXECUTEONLYONCE or WT_EXECUTELONGFUNCTION); // и вот здесь ExternalException
  if not bResult then
    RaiseLastOSError;
end;
```

Stacktrace:

```
:76f3a6e2 KERNELBASE.RaiseException + 0x62
:00409b50 NotifyNonDelphiException + $1C
:778f8894 ; 
:778e4ec6 ntdll.KiUserExceptionDispatcher + 0x26
:77901855 ; 
:778a7b7c ntdll.TpSetWaitEx + 0x8c
:778a21d9 ; 
:765e7a7d KERNEL32.RegisterWaitForSingleObject + 0x3d
Unit20.TForm20.btn1Click($329DDE0)
```

Насколько я понимаю - это одна из самых базовых функций в WinAPI, поэтому вряд ли там будет какая-то ошибка, соответственно - это должна быть кривизна моих рук. Вот только в чем?

Дополнительная информация:
IDE: XE2 и 10.4.1, компиляция в 32бит, идентичная ошибка с идентичными стектрейсами на обеих
OS: Windows 10 Pro x64.
И под дебаггером и без - результат аналогичен.

Comment: Вот [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34549019) пишут, что мютексы нельзя использовать.

Comment: @zed там шарповая обертка, которая вполне может использовать собственную реализацию (и пруфов "нельзя вот по этому" там нет). А секция Remarks искомой функции прямо упоминает о возможности использовать mutex-ы... Как-то хочется доверять официальным докам :). Собственно, сама функция-то работает, хендл потока, к примеру, она проглатывает на ура. А мьютекс - не хочет.

Comment: Вот [тут](http://joeduffyblog.com/2007/05/13/registerwaitforsingleobject-and-mutexes-dont-mix/) объясняется, почему в C# нельзя, а в WinAPI (если очень хочется) вроде как можно, но только с флагом `WT_EXECUTEINWAITTHREAD` и этого делать вообще не рекомендуется.

Comment: @zed, да, вот эта фраза всё объясняет, дальше можно не читать: `when a wait for a mutex is satisfied, the thread which performed the wait now owns the mutex`. Если опубликуете ответ - я приму, спасибо.

Comment: Объяснения, почему происходит исключение, всё-таки нет.

Comment: а если передать в качестве 4 параметра не nil, a Self? ...WaitCallback, Self, INFINITE...

Comment: @NMD нет, не помогает. Это же всего лишь проксируемый в коллбак параметр, системой он не используется. В реально-тестовом коде я использовал и ссылку на объект, и ссылки на структуры в памяти (нужны для работы коллбака) - результат идентичен.